# Why won't npm install any packages?

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, sails.js

I've been attempting to get an install of SailsJS working for 3 hours now.

I have now created a totally fresh Linux Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit VM and have followed a dozen different tutorials for how to install NodeJS / SailsJS (including the tutorial from within the documentation) ALL to no avail.

The error I am getting is as follows (when I attempt to run `sudo npm -g install sails`):

```
npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-29-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "-g" "install" "sails"
npm ERR! cwd /home/asdf/Desktop
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.21
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! stack     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
npm ERR! stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/asdf/Desktop/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Does anybody have any idea what might be causing me my issues? I've followed the tutorial very precisely and on a totally fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 and now I'm just pulling my hair out.

Comment: Network problem . Connection refused. Double check your network settings.

Comment: I figured as much, but what network settings? It's a fresh install of an Ubuntu VM using VMWarePlayer on Windows 8. I have an ethernet cable plugged directly into the laptop, getting internet access both in and out of the VM. Not sure what else I'd have to do.

Comment: it has nothing to do with your system. The problem are on the npm servers themselves.

Answer (score 5):

that default use proxy http://127.0.0.1.8087

so execute:

```
npm config set proxy null
```

Answer (score 3):

npmjs.org has had some downtime issues today. Just wait and try later.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be having issues now, and my co-worker just installed fine on his macbook